# Does this enum have 2 names? How do I convert it to an NS_ENUM?

Tags: objective-c, enums, 32bit-64bit

While converting Objective-C `enum`s to `NS_ENUM`s, I came across  like this, which seems strange to me:

```
enum nameA{
    valueA=1,
    valueB,
    // ...
    valueN
}nameB;
```

In the code, `nameA` and `nameB` were two different names. **Does this `enum` have *both* `nameA` *and* `nameB` as its name? How would I convert it to an `NS_ENUM`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is equivalent to:

```
enum nameA {
   ...
};
enum nameA nameB;
```

So it's not just a declaration of an enumeration, it's also the definition of a variable of that type. You'll need to take that into account when doing your translation. Something like:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, nameA) {
    ...
};
nameA nameB;
```